# McAfee antivirus causing Delphi application to throw EFCreateError

Tags: delphi, antivirus

Our Delphi 5 popular application is running fine on almost all client computers. On some computers it constantly throws EFCreateError exceptions during write-to-disk operations like `TFileStream.Create` and `TStrings.SaveToFile`. These computers run McAfee, so it seems plausible that McAfee is background-scanning the file while our app tries to write to the file.

Its a sporadic problem as it doesn't occur every time, but like in one out of 20 save operations. Since these saves are background actions our users trigger indirectly, they cannot try again to save.

The calls are from frameworks we use, such as JEDI's JvFormStorage. while we could change it to try to save up to 5 times, it still seems rather brittle to me.

The software has never been identified as bad by any antivirus (checked by VirusTotal). Instead it seems like the antivirus is using a blocking read operation to do its job.

Comment: This is just a fact of life with AV software. There's not very much you can do about it. Other than get some decent AV software.

Comment: Most decent AV solutions keep a detailed log of activity that you should check before jumping to conclusions, altho I don't know if you can count McAfee AV under decent.

Comment: Recommend that your users exclude your data folder from the real-time scanning.

Comment: The only way around is to open files with shared read access (ie `ShareDenyNone` or `ShareDenyWrite`)...

Comment: Could you tell us _where_ you're writing files. It may be that what McAfee is seeing trouble with.

Comment: The files are being written in a sub-directory of the Desktop. They are INI-like ASCII files. I could imagine that the trouble is that files are being written to frequently. The first write triggers McAfee's background check and the next write fails in case McAfee is still doing its thing.